# Multiple subtitles on Videos doesn't work

Tags: 16.04

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using Videos. When two people are talking at the same time, there's supposed to be two subtitles displaying, yet only the first one appears; the second one never displays. It works correctly in VLC. Is this fixable in Videos 3.18?

Comment: What subtitle file format? And is this the case of one subtitle file that has two dialogues with overlapping times? Some more details would really help.

Comment: It seems to happen with every subtitle format (at least the ones I've tried). Yes, I am referring to when two dialogues have overlapping times.

Comment: I'm using Videos 3.18.1-1ubuntu4 but the problem is still there (for an srt file anyway). I don't see any setting that would affect this. From Help --> About you can send feedback or  make a bug report. I guess the other question would be why not just use VLC Player?

Comment: I'm having a separate problem with VLC, described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064817/when-i-skip-to-a-different-time-in-vlc-theres-lag-and-visual-distortions