# When I skip to a different time in VLC, there's lag and visual distortions

Tags: 16.04, vlc

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using the latest stable version of VLC from the repository. My gpu is a GTX 950 with the binary driver if that's relevant. When I'm watching a video in VLC and I skip to a different time, it takes like 8 seconds to load, plus the visuals are all distorted for about another 4 seconds afterwards. Is there any way to mitigate this? It's quite annoying at times. I'm having neither of these problems with Ubuntu Videos 3.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I *seem* to have fixed it by doing this: Tools -> Preferences -> Video -> Output: changing it from "Automatic" to "X11 Video Output (XCB)". I'll update if the problem comes back.